# AES-128 bit byte arrays to database in java

Tags: java, encryption, aes

I have a String (stringToEncrypt) , it is encrypted by AES-128 and got a byte[]. I try to write that byte[] to database as a String. An example below :

`String encryptedString = new String(aes.encode(stringToEncrypt.getBytes()));`

"encode" method gets a byte[] as parameter and returns a byte[]. "aes" object makes the AES-128 encoding process.
The problem is, when i try to write encryptedString to DB, some characters that are written to DB is not the same as "String encryptedString". I think the problem is about the charset of DB or on my code. Any suggestions please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`String` is the wrong data type for your problem. If you really need to encode raw bytes to a string, use [base64](http://commons.apache.org/codec/apidocs/org/apache/commons/codec/binary/Base64.html).

If it is possible, try to store `byte[]` directly into the database.

Comment: Thank you Otto! I used Base64 for aes.encode and returned it as String, after that wrote to DB! Thank you very much.

Comment: Also, don't use `String.getBytes()`; use `String.getBytes("UTF-8")`. Don't use the `String(byte[])` constructor; use `String(byte[], "UTF-8")`.

Comment: @GregS good point, although it should be pointed out that the encoding could be something different than "UTF-8"

Comment: If you have a String, UTF-8 always works to encode. But you're right, to decode with the String constructor you must know what encoding was used. So I say just always use UTF-8 to encode and decode.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, its a character encoding issue.  I've seen it in another place before.  I would either base64 encode it or store it as a biginteger.

```
// byte array[];
BigInteger value = new BigInteger(array);
```

You can cheat with BigInteger and use it to Base64 things too:

```
String b64 = value.toString(64);
```

[BigInteger documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html)

Comment: Thank you Wug! I used Base64 for aes.encode and returned it as String and problem solved! Thank you very much.

Comment: Hello Wug, i cannot vote because it says "vote up requires 15 reputation" thank you.